# Getting error while using stevenmaguire/oauth2-keycloak with keycloak 22.01 version

Tags: php, jwt, keycloak, openid-connect

I need connect my PHP app with keycloak 22.01 version for authenticating purpose. but I am getting an error while getting the resource owner information . I had tried all the things but does not resolve my error.

my php version is 7.4

my composer.json

```
{
    "require": {
        "stevenmaguire/oauth2-keycloak": "^5.0"
    }
}
```

Error :

> Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: Failed to parse JSON response:
> Syntax error in
> /opt/lampp/htdocs/Demo/vendor/league/oauth2-client/src/Provider/AbstractProvider.php:645
> Stack trace:
> #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/Demo/vendor/league/oauth2-client/src/Provider/AbstractProvider.php(686):
> League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\AbstractProvider->parseJson(NULL)
> #1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/Demo/vendor/stevenmaguire/oauth2-keycloak/src/Provider/Keycloak.php(378):
> League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\AbstractProvider->parseResponse(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response))
> #2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/Demo/vendor/league/oauth2-client/src/Provider/AbstractProvider.php(626):
> Stevenmaguire\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Keycloak->parseResponse(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response))
> #3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/Demo/vendor/league/oauth2-client/src/Provider/AbstractProvider.php(784):
> League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\AbstractProvider->getParsedResponse(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request))
> #4 /opt/lampp/htdocs/Demo/vendor/stevenmaguire/oauth2-keycloak/src/Provider/Keycloak.php(271):
> League\OAuth2\ in
> /opt/lampp/htdocs/Demo/vendor/league/oauth2-client/src/Provider/AbstractProvider.php
> on line 645

I had tried

```
   $provider = new Stevenmaguire\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Keycloak([
    'authServerUrl'         => 'http://localhost:8080',
    'realm'                 => 'Demo',
    'clientId'              => 'email',
    'clientSecret'          => '{keycloak-client-secret}',
    'redirectUri'           => 'http://localhost/Demo/',
    'encryptionAlgorithm'   => 'RS256',                             // optional
]);

if (!isset($_GET['code'])) {
    // If we don't have an authorization code then get one
    $authUrl = $provider->getAuthorizationUrl();
    $_SESSION['oauth2state'] = $provider->getState();
    header('Location: '.$authUrl);
    exit;

} elseif (empty($_GET['state']) || ($_GET['state'] !== $_SESSION['oauth2state'])) {

    unset($_SESSION['oauth2state']);
    exit('Invalid state, make sure HTTP sessions are enabled.');

} else {

    $token = $provider->getAccessToken('authorization_code', [
        'code' => $_GET['code']
    ]);
  
    $user = $provider->getResourceOwner($token);
    print_r($user);
    try {
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        exit('Failed to get access token: '.$e->getMessage());

    }

    try {

        $user = $provider->getResourceOwner($token);

        print_r($provider);

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        exit('Failed to get resource owner: '.$e->getMessage());
    }

    echo $token->getToken();
   }
```

Comment: According to https://github.com/stevenmaguire/oauth2-keycloak/issues/66 , you need the version ID

Comment: `I had tried all the things`...this is meaningless unfortunately. Unless we know specifically what things you've tried and what the outcomes were, we cannot rule them out. It might save us all a lot of time if you were more specific.

Comment: But now my requirement is php 5.6.31

Comment: Fatal error: Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 7.2.0". You are running 5.6.31. in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Demo/vendor/composer/platform_check.php on line 25

Getting this kind of error